# begin() and end() for STL algorithms

Tags: c++, stl-algorithm

I have a class whose data container is backed by an array, and I have the following implementations for `begin()` and `end()`.

```
template <size_t size>
double * MyContainerClass<size>::begin(){
    return std::begin(mContainer);
}

template <size_t size>
double * MyContainerClass<size>::end(){
    return std::end(mContainer);
}
```

In other member functions, I am attempting to use `begin()` and `end()` for STL algorithms such as `std::transform` and `std::copy`. When `const` objects are passed as parameters to these member functions, I encounter the error:

> error: passing '`const MyContainerClass<size>`' as '`this`' argument discards qualifiers.
>   note: in call to '`double* MyContainerClass<size>::begin()` [with `unsigned int size = size`]'

Is this caused by incorrect `begin()` and `end()` implementations?

```
std::copy(begin(), end(), someOutputIterator);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this caused by incorrect begin() and end() implementations?

Yes, you need `const` versions of the functions. For example:

```
template <size_t size>
const double * MyContainerClass<size>::begin() const {
    return std::begin(mContainer);
}
```

Comment: Do I need to provide both the const and non-const implementations to be fully compliant to the STL algorithms, or would that be dependent upon the application of my class?

Comment: Yes, you should in general provide both.

Comment: @Skipher You only need the non-const versions if you want to allow modifying the data in the container through iterators.

Answer (score 4):

The important word here is 'const': You need to provide additional `const` versions of your `begin()` and `end()` functions, that return `const double*`.

If you are using C++ 11, you may also want to provide `cbegin()` and `cend()`.